# SQLite Sum of Sums

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have two tables which look like this:

```
Games:
| AwayTeam  | HomeTeam     | AwayPoints | HomePoints |
------------------------------------------------------
| Aardvarks | Bobcats      | 2          | 1          |
| Bobcats   | Caterpillars | 20         | 10         |
| Aardvarks | Caterpillars | 200        | 100        |

Teams:
| Name         | 
----------------
| Aardvarks    | 
| Bobcats      |
| Caterpillars |
```

How can I make a result which looks like this?

```
| Name         | TotalPoints |
------------------------------
| Aardvarks    | 202         |
| Bobcats      |  21         | 
| Caterpillars | 110         |
```

---

I think my real problem is how to splice statements together in SQL.  These two statements work well individually:

```
SELECT SUM ( AwayPoints ) 
FROM   Games 
WHERE  AwayTeam='Bobcats';

SELECT SUM ( HomePoints ) 
FROM   Games 
WHERE  HomeTeam='Bobcats';
```

I suspect that I need a [compound operator](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/compound-operator.html) if I want to splice two [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) statements togeather. Then pass that statement into the aggregate expression below:

```
SELECT   Name, SUM( aggregate_expression ) 
AS       'TotalPoints' 
FROM     Teams 
GROUP BY Name;
```

---

If I had to just throw it all together, I think I'd end up with something like this:

```
SELECT   Name, SUM (
    SELECT SUM ( AwayPoints ) 
    FROM   Games 
    WHERE  AwayTeam=Name 
  UNION 
    SELECT SUM ( HomePoints )
    FROM   Games 
    WHERE  HomeTeam=Name
)
AS       'TotalPoints' 
FROM     Teams 
GROUP BY Name;
```

However that doesn't work because `SELECT SUM ( SELECT ...` is completely invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT team, SUM(points)
FROM (
  SELECT HomeTeam AS team, SUM(HomePoints) AS points
  FROM Games
  GROUP BY HomeTeam
 UNION ALL
  SELECT AwayTeam AS team, SUM(AwayPoints) AS points
  FROM Games
  GROUP BY AwayTeam
)
GROUP BY team
```

See SQLite documentation for

- [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) [expr AS alias](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/result-column.html)
- [SELECT ... FROM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) [( select-stmt ) AS table-alias](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-or-subquery.html)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `SELECT expr AS alias` syntax.  Or the `FROM ( select-stmt ) AS table-alias`.  Thanks